# Causing crash when serialize using NSJSONSerialization in iOS

Tags: ios, json, crash, nsjsonserialization

In my iPhone application I am calling a webservice using JSON. And I using `NSJSONSerialization` for retrieving the data from service. I am getting crash at random points when I run the app. Here is the screen shot of the issue.
 [image: screen shot]

Can someone please check it? If need more code, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the message in the exception?

Comment: Check if `currentResult` is nil before `NSJSONSerialization` is called...

Comment: @trojanfoe I didn't get any message in the log, i added a exception break point, so i could track the exact point.

Comment: @jjv360 I will do that. So, if the currentResult is nil, will that cause the issue?

Comment: Yes it can, you need to do a `if (currentResult == nil) { /* Failed... */ }` before trying to parse it...

Comment: You need to *Continue* in the debugger so that the exception message will be logged.

Comment: Ok, I will do. Also, we can see some function calls in the left side of the image right? How can I understand the reason for it from that? I am getting some crash at some other points also, I just want to understand the exact reason for that.

Comment: The exact reason for an exception is typically expressed by the exception message as @trojanfoe is suggesting. Get that and share it here to help debug the issue.